# What is the procedure to ask for a reopen when you don't have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79439/how-to-deal-with-players-that-wants-their-characters-to-do-automatic-perception) was closed as a duplicate of another question. However, I think that it is *related* but not a *duplicate* since the linked question is system-agnostic. Indeed, D&D 5e has specific rules and player options for perception/investigation-related "standing orders", so I believe I could contribute a quality answer to the question.

I would like to vote to reopen the question, but lack the reputation to do so. What is the procedure to ask for a reopen vote to be cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a formal one; reopen voting privileges are granted based on demonstrated experience with the site and subject (measured approximately by reputation), and not having gained the close/reopen voting privilege means not getting a say in such things yet.

That said, there are two informal ways:

### Flagging

You can in theory flag a closed question for moderation attention, but that's only useful in exceptional cases where something has clearly gone wrong, and moderator intervention is needed. For the more normal case of just wanting to cast a reopen vote and not having one, a mod flag would likely be declined in favour of letting close/reopen voters take care of it.

### Ask for input on Meta

You can also make a case for reopening on Meta. This is useful for odd corner cases where it's not obvious why it should be closed/open, and the community can chew on it to figure out the best treatment for the question. That might be useful in this case.

(This question here is too general to inspire that kind of conversation though; a meta of that kind needs a specific line of reasoning or description of the problem or corner case that's causing concern for the community to engage with it productively. For example, it may not be obvious to others how there could be an answer unique to D&D 5e; bringing that up directly as an example of how they're different questions might be productive.)

Comment: That's a bummer. Understandable, but still a bummer. I could have added a good answer to the question. I guess I'll just have to lurk to see if someone else casts a reopen vote.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that improving the question to make it more obviously similar-but-not-a-duplicate is an option, and doing that successfully improves the chances of it being reopened by others.

Comment: @Anaphory …but is something that we discourage users who aren't the author from doing. If the question can be reworded without changing its meaning then it doesn't need rewording to see that it's not a duplicate, and if it needs rewording to see that it's not a duplicate, then only the original author knows what they were trying to say enough to make that kind of change to its meaning.

Comment: Question-specific re-open request, with reasoning: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/can-we-please-reopen-a-related-but-not-duplicate-question